# wrong function being picked

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I was trying to clean up some code that uses `char*` with `std::string` and ran into a problem that is illustrated by the following code.

```
void Foo( int xIn , const std::string & fooIn )
{
    std::cout << "string argument version called \n";
}

void Foo( int xIn ,  bool flagIn = true )
{
    std::cout << "bool argument version called \n";
}

int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    Foo( x , "testing" );
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the program I get **bool argument version called**.  Is a `char*` to `bool` conversion preferred over `char*` to `const std::string&` or is Visual Studio 2008 playing tricks on me ?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663724/wrong-argument-conversion-preferred-when-calling-function

Comment: Cleaned up the formatting a bit & removed irrelevant Windows stuff.

Comment: I normally avoid implicit conversion in C++ because it is so easy to get some unexpected behaviour (bug).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Surprising as this behaviour is, the compiler is compliant: `char*` to `bool` conversion is preferred over the conversion to `std::string`.

Read more [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2008/06/05/some-c-gotchas.aspx).

The exact rules are spelled out in the C++ standard. They're surprisingly complicated, but the following paragraph is crucial here:

> C++11 **13.3.3.2 Ranking implicit conversion sequences [over.ics.rank]**
>
> 2
>   When comparing the basic forms of implicit conversion sequences (as
>   defined in 13.3.3.1) — a standard conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.1) is
>   a better conversion sequence than a user-defined conversion sequence
>   or an ellipsis conversion sequence

`char*`-to-`bool` requires a "standard conversion sequence" whereas `char*`-to-`string` requires a "user-defined conversion sequence". Therefore, the former is preferred.

Comment: @Vlad.. what is the **safe bool** alternative ?

Comment: @vlad: The misbehaving type is built-in. What do you mean?

Comment: @Vlad: The [safe bool idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Safe_bool) is useful when you want your user-defined type to provide a conversion to bool. Here, the conversion is between two primitive types, so the safe bool idiom is not applicable.

Comment: @UncleBens I mean this - http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html  So instead of using built-in bool, you can use this wrapper to avoid the char * vs bool problem in ADL.

Comment: @LucTouraille: You are right. I meant replacing `bool` with some sort of `Safebool` in the method when users really mean bool... One could also use enable_if to prevent `const char *` from being passed. Just thoughts.

Comment: That's quite different than the "safe bool idiom"

Answer (score 9):

They are both a potential match, but the `bool` version is preferred by the compiler because in order to match the `string` version a user-provided (or, in this case, library-provided) conversion function is required.

If you really want to do this, providing an overload for `const char*` can get you there:

```
void Foo( int xIn, const char* in)
{
    return Foo( xIn, string(in) );
}
```

I would guess that by doing this, there's a very good chance that the compiler will perform quite a bit of optimization on it.

Comment: I mentioned in my question... I ran into this while cleaning up **char*** version to begin with

Answer (score 1):

One simple fix would be to change the `bool` to `int` - there is an implicit conversion from a pointer to `bool`, but not to `int`. `bool` to `int` is not a problem, so the existing code that passes bools will continue to work.

Unfortunately this does impact the code readability a little by masking the parameter's intent.