# What overloaded C++ function will be called?

Tags: c++, overloading

Here is the subject of the topic:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void test(bool val)
{
    std::cout << "bool" << std::endl;
}

void test(std::string val)
{
    std::cout << "std::string" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    test("hello");
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the program is `bool`. Why the `bool` variant selected?

Comment: Ask yourself: what’s the type of `"hello"` and what can it be converted to?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8359260/1171191

Comment: This is going to become more common a problem. Advocates of Modern C++ (including me) are not teaching char* strings first, or even at all. Yet literal strings are char* and clearly this is becoming unintuitive for newcomers. It's a real problem.

Comment: @KateGregory: technically literals are *arrays of characters*, not *pointers to characters* (this is a longstanding fight against the misconception that arrays are pointers...)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas not going to argue that; the point remains that if we leave char* and char[] and "arrays are not pointers but ..." until chapter 17, folks are going to stumble across wrinkles like this and be confused.

Comment: Part of the issue is that we want newcomers to think of all of std:: as being "built in" but the standard and the compiler consider them "user defined" just like our own Employee or NuclearReactor types.

Comment: @KateGregory: Do we really want to teach that? I have always considered that it is important to make clear that the standard library is full of *user defined* types, on which you can depend, but that are not much different than what you can write (as a matter of fact we use our own implementation of the standard library where I work, and I hope and expect it not to be lesser than the one that ships with the compiler!) I believe that what we want is to have new comers understand and use the library feature for what it offers, and giving it a halo of magic... not sure I want to go there.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas in module/chap 1 yes, I want to teach that std:: is always there and can be counted on. At some point I will explain that there is no magic and you could have written this all yourself. Wrinkles like this suggest that overloading needs to move after "behind the curtain" on std:: and possibly after char*/char[] and rules of type promotion - none of which I want to deal with for complete beginners. I'm still chewing this over.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To call the `bool` overload requires the following conversion:

```
const char[6] ---> const char* ---> bool
```

To call the `std::string` overload requires the following conversion:

```
const char[6] ---> const char* ---> std::string
```

This involves a user-defined conversion (using the conversion constructor of `std::string`). Any conversion sequence without a user-defined conversion is preferred over a sequence with a user-defined conversion.

> When comparing the basic forms of implicit conversion sequences (as defined in 13.3.3.1):
>
> - a standard conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.1) is a better conversion sequence than a user-defined conversion sequence or an ellipsis conversion sequence, and
> - [...]

A standard conversion sequence is one involving only standard conversions. A user-defined conversion sequence is one involving a single user-defined conversion.

Answer (score 6):

That is because `"hello"` has type `const char[6]`, which decays to `const char*`, which in turn can be converted into `bool` by means of another *standard conversion*. Therefore, the overall conversion:

```
const char[6] -> bool
```

Can be performed *just by means of standard conversions*.

On the other hand, converting a `const char*` to an `std::string` would require a user-defined conversion (invoking the converting constructor of `std::string`), and **standard conversions are preferable over user-defined conversions** when doing overload resolution.

Comment: Why do people keep insisting in going through `void*` for the conversion to `bool`? *Any* pointer can be converted to a `bool` *directly* (4.12 *A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to member type can be converted to a prvalue of type bool. A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to false; any other value is converted to true.*)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: You're right. I overlooked that, and it's not the first time. Thank you for pointing out, I edited the answer.